# How do I group nested lists based on the first element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list containing strings which I want to group based on the first element of a nested list. After grouping them, I then want to remove any duplicate first elements and convert the list to a simple string seperated by a semicolon.

What I have managed so far is to output the simple string as well as removing duplicate first elements. I did this by saving the first element of the list in a new empty list, and using the if/else statement to decide what to append to the new output list.

```
exampleinput = ["[['1','2','3'],['1','4','6'],['2','1','2'],['3','4','2'], ['1','2','5'],['1','7','8']]"]

def makestring(n):
  str1 = ' '.join(n)
  return str1

def transform(n):
  first = []
  output = []
  for i in n:
    if i[0] not in first:
      output.append(makestring(i))
    else:
      string1 = makestring(i[1:])
      output.append(string1)
    first.append(i[0])
  return output

for i in exampleinput:
  print(transform(eval(i.strip())))
```

**Example input:**

```
[['1','2','3'],['1','4','6'],['2','1','2'],['3','4','2'],['1','2','5'],['1','7','8']]
```

**Desired output:**

```
['1 2 3 ; 4 6 ; 2 5 ; 7 8', '2 1 2', ' 3 4 2']
```

---

**Actual output:**

```
['1 2 3', '4 6', '2 1 2', '3 4 2, '2 5', '7 8']
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function:

```
from itertools import groupby

inp_list = [['1','2','3'],['1','4','6'],['2','1','2'],['3','4','2'],['1','2','5'],['1','7','8']]
res = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(inp_list, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    item1, *rest = g
    res.append('; '.join(map(' '.join, [item1] + [i[1:] for i in rest])) 
               if rest else ' '.join(item1))

print(res)
```

The output:

```
['1 2 3; 4 6; 2 5; 7 8', '2 1 2', '3 4 2']
```

---

**Bonus** solution with just using an auxiliary grouping dictionary:

```
inp_list = [['1','2','3'],['1','4','6'],['2','1','2'],['3','4','2'],['1','2','5'],['1','7','8']]
groups_dict = {}
for sub_l in inp_list:
    if sub_l[0] not in groups_dict:
        groups_dict[sub_l[0]] = ' '.join(sub_l)
    else:
        groups_dict[sub_l[0]] += '; ' + ' '.join(sub_l[1:])
res = list(groups_dict.values())

print(res)   # ['1 2 3; 4 6; 2 5; 7 8', '2 1 2', '3 4 2']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution! Would it be different/more difficult to do this without an imported function? I'm still new at Python and I would like to understand what the thought process would be to tackle such a problem.

Comment: @MatthewK., you have my bonus solution, enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending to string one you are appending to the output in the order which given. Here is the code I got to work:

```
exampleinput = ["[['1','2','3'],['1','4','6'],['2','1','2'],['3','4','2'], ['1','2','5'],['1','7','8']]"]

def makestring(i):
    return "".join(i)

def main(i):
    string1 = ""
    first = ["1"] # for (123)
    output = []
    string1 += makestring(i[0])
    for x in i[1:]:
        if x[0] in first:
            string1 += " ; "+makestring(x[1:])
        else:
            output.append(makestring(x))
            first.append(x[0])
    return [string1] + output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main(eval(exampleinput[0].strip())))
```

This returns the output:
    ['123 ; 46 ; 25 ; 78', '212', '342']

Answer (score 0):

First I use the join method to create a list of strings

```
signal = [['1','2','3'],['1','4','6'],['2','1','2'],['3','4','2'],['1','2','5'],['1','7','8']]
my_list =[" ".join(x) for x in [y for y in signal] ]
```

then search list from end to start to the comparison the first character of that string is in other items if it's true and it's not same item and index of 
 item greater than item that selected then removes it.

```
for i in range(len(my_list)-1,0,-1):
    for j in my_list:
        if my_list[i][0] == j[0] and my_list[i] != j and i > my_list.index(j):
            my_list[i]= my_list[i][1:]

print(my_list)
```

output:

```
['1 2 3', ' 4 6', '2 1 2', '3 4 2', ' 2 5', ' 7 8']
```